# How to configure IBM Cloud CloudFoundry Apps to support IPV6

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ipv6

our App has been rejected by Apple because it does not work on pure IPV6 networks. We think it is because IBM CloudFoundry App hosting does not support it. How can we enable the IBM cloud foundry address such as tbms-proxy.eu-gb.mybluemix.net to be IPV6 compliant? thanks

Comment: Cloud Foundry in general (and some other cloud technologies) seem to have that problem. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/enabling_ipv6.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a custom domain, one option could be to go through a gateway to enable IPv6.

[Cloud Internet Services](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/internet-svcs) can do this by proxying requests to your app. Cloud Internet Services is powered by [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com).

Once your domain is configured in Cloud Internet Services and [added to IBM Cloud](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/apps/updapps.html#updatingapps), [IPv6 connectivity](https://www.cloudflare.com/ipv6/) will be available.